# Extend an interface using an existing interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this interface in typescript:

```js
interface VolRenderingProps extends JSX.mesh {
    // Additional props
    url: string
    interpolation?: number
    alphaCorrection?: number
    steps?: number
}
```

I need to separate the additional props from the declaration itself (because I need to use the type `AdditionalProps` in other place). So Im trying to do something like:

```js
interface AdditionalProps {
    url: string
    interpolation?: number
    alphaCorrection?: number
    steps?: number
}
interface VolRenderingProps extends JSX.mesh {
   ...AdditionalProps // I suppose this is totally wrong but you get the idea :)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `VolRenderingProps` to extend multiple interfaces - so `JSX.mesh` and `AdditionalProps`.  Please check the following code:

```
interface AdditionalProps {
    url: string
    interpolation?: number
    alphaCorrection?: number
    steps?: number
}
interface VolRenderingProps extends JSX.mesh, AdditionalProps {
   // and so on
}
```